# Is this how super() is working in my code?

Tags: python, class

The following example was given in my python book:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
    def area(self):
        return (self.width * self.length)
    
class Square(Rectangle):  
    def __init__(self, side_length):
        super().__init__(side_length, side_length)    
     
shape = Square(4)
print(shape.area())
```

The programme prints 16.

From what I understand, super() looks for the init method within the parent class (which is Rectangle). It finds it and makes it use the side_length attribute for length and width. Then, area() is called with the variable side_length. Is this how the code is working or have I misunderstood it?

Comment: just wanted to introduce the topic; but your right, it's irrelevant

Comment: This is a classic example of violating a SOLID principle. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/381675/why-does-the-square-rectangle-problem-violate-solid-principles

Comment: You can verify your understanding by stepping through the code with a debugger, inspecting variables.